# Error: Cannot find control with name: 'idBed'

Tags: angular

i'm working on project using angular / spring boot i'm facing this error when trying to add input to my form , all input are working expect this one

**front code**

```
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <i> <label for="validationCu">bed</label> </i> 
       <select class="form-control"   aria-label="Default select example"
       placeholder=" idBed "
       formControlName="idBed" 
        [(ngModel)]="patient.idBed"
        #idBed 
       >
         <option value="23">B1</option>
         <option value="23">B2</option>
         <option value="23">B3</option>
       
       </select>
      </div>
```

```
export class Patient {

    id:number;
    username:string;
    email:string;
    password:string;
    firstname:string;
    lastname:string;
    numcode:string;
    gender:string;
    rome:string;
    idBed:number;
    constructor(){}
    
}
```

```
loginPatient(){

         this._service.loginPatientFormRemote(this.patient).subscribe(
           data =>{ 
             
            console.log(data);
            this.patient = new Patient();
            this.isCreated = true;
            this.patientError = new Patient();
```

Comment: Why are you using `formControlName` and `ngModel` on the control? That will not work. Use one or the other.

Comment: when i delete formControlName , i get this error `core.js:6210 ERROR Error: 
      ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:

      
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, try many time to change the input, is what exactly i did and know it works, i don't know what is the problem with angular in this case we hade this error

```
 Error: Cannot find control with name: 'idBed'
```

which means that the formControllerName doest existe but  it's already existe.

Answer (score 0):

I  your .component.ts you need to define an object patient: Patient and maybe instantiate it.
if you are populating it from a service you will need to make a service call like

```
this.service.getBeds().subscribe(beds => 
this.patientBeds = beds);
```

and do a *ngFor in your mat-select

Comment: i added .component.js please check it

Comment: your class Patient, need to have code in the constructor like constructor(id:number){ this.id=id; ...}

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: sorry my mistake I think the answer by Richard will work

Comment: formControllname need to be patient.bedId as bedid isn't known

Comment: same , didn't work , even R. Richards solution didn't work